# Override CSS Styling

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Is there a way to override a class completely?

In woocommerce, I have this code in the stylesheet:

```
.woocommerce-review-link {
        bottom: 0;
        display: block;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
```

I want it to become:

```
 .woocommerce-review-link {
bottom: -4px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
right: 180px;
top: 0;
}
```

But when I enter that in the custom CSS box in my theme, it still uses the previous CSS for the parts I didn't add:

```
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="woocommerce-product-rating">

<a href="#reviews" class="woocommerce-review-link" rel="nofollow">(<span class="count">2</span> customer reviews)</a>   </div>
```

Comment: You could just use !important

Comment: Never use !important

Comment: No I can't.  That is only overriding the parts I want.  I want to remove the "left" & "opacity".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "remove" styling from a styled element, you need to set it back to the default/initial value. In this case, you need `left: auto` and `opacity: 1`.

What you're getting hung up on is [the *cascading* part of *Cascading Style Sheets*.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance) Styles to a selected element are aggregate, with later styles simply overriding previously-defined styles. Even your initial styling on a brand new site is simply overwriting past styles, since the browser starts with a certain amount of styling on the most common elements (this is why an `<h1></h1>` is large and bold even with nothing else on a page, for example).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the element name before the class to override, like:

```
    <element>.woocommerce-review-link {
        bottom: -4px;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 180px;
        top: 0;
    }
```

if it is a link then:

```
a.woocommerce-review-link {
      bottom: -4px;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      right: 180px;
      top: 0;
}
```

or you can also use the id with class, basically any selector that gets more priority over .woocommerce-review-link

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned it's a link.

<div class="woocommerce-product-rating">

<a href="#reviews" class="woocommerce-review-link" rel="nofollow">(<span class="count">2</span> customer reviews)</a> </div>

Answer (score 0):

The rule is when you select an element with more details, its rules will be applied in greater priorities. In your case, you can assign an id to `element` and customize class `woocommerce-review-link`.for example

```
<a id="customized" class="woocommerce-review-link" href="#">Sth</a>

#customized.woocommerce-review-link{
    bottom: -4px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 180px;
    top: 0;
}
.woocommerce-review-link {
        bottom: 0;
        display: block;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
```

Here because you select  tag in more specefic details using `#customized.woocommerce-review-link`, its rules will have greater priorities than selecting just using `.woocommerce-review-link`.

Answer (score 0):

**!important** is best for that you add !important after all elements like this

```
 .woocommerce-review-link {
bottom: -4px !important;
display: block !important;
position: absolute !important;
right: 180px !important;
top: 0 !important;
}
```

So it automatically use **!important** element first

Answer (score 0):

Add a new class with that one:

```
.woocommerce-review-link {
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.woocommerce-review-link.changed {
    bottom: -4px;
    right: 180px;
}

<a href="#reviews" class="woocommerce-review-link changed" rel="nofollow">(<span class="count">2</span> customer reviews)</a>
```

You should never enter same values in changed class, only the one that you are changing.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the values of directives `left`, `opacity` to `left: auto`, `opacity: 1` in the page's main container element. Using `!important` to force is different matter.

```css
    woocommerce-product-rating woocommerce-review-link,
    a.woocommerce-review-link, 
    a.woocommerce-review-link:link,
    a.woocommerce-review-link:visited,
    a.woocommerce-review-link:hover,
    a.woocommerce-review-link:active  { bottom: -4px !important; display: block !important; position: absolute !important; right: 180px !important; 
    top: 0 !important; }
    a.woocommerce-review-link:hover { color:red !important; }
```

```html
<div class="woocommerce-product-rating">

    <a href="#reviews" class="woocommerce-review-link" rel="nofollow">(<span class="count">2</span> customer reviews)</a>   </div>
```

Comment: OK, so if I want to remove pre-defined CSS, I need to add them as "default" so to speak?